# Is there a way to hide menu items from specific admin ID's in Wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, css, arrays, wordpress

I have 3 admin accounts: one admin for me (shows everything) and 2 others where they need admin access to most items.

I was able to hide the main menu items (posts, pages, comments, appearance, etc) in the functions, however what about hiding menu items that are created from a plugin or other ones that are not part of the Wordpress central menu item list?

For example, Contact Form 7 Database creates 'Contact Forms' on the side bar menu or Google  Google Site Kit creates 'Site Kit', and I have others where id like to hide them based on the username or user ID.

anyone know how to do that?

Comment: First of all: hiding menu items is called "security by obscurity" and here means that if somebody knows the url of the contact form administration, they can simply type it into their browser and will see the page. Anyway, I'd approach this from the other direction: instead of hiding dozens of potential items, just hide every item by default and turn them on only for you.

Comment: In the long run I'd assign them a different role but I don't know how easy/hard it is to customize WP roles. On the other hand, I just googled "wordpress custom roles" and immediately found this: https://wordpress.org/plugins/members/

Answer (score 0):

You can use such a Jewish method, which of course it does not promote, but it is effective:
There is function in wordpress `get_role( string $role )`. You can just one of two methods:

1. For lazy people. Just call function in functions.php that generate some css with display:none for individual users.
2. Second, is similar. Just find where plugin or theme generates these items and use function mentioned above to render them for individual roles.
   I recommend using String Locator plugin to find code in site.